# Pressing one UIButton triggers another UIButton: I don't want this to happen

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uibutton

I am new to swift and xcode and am having a little trouble with creating this simple timer app with laps. When I press on the 'lap' button, the 'reset button is also triggered. Can anyone please help me with this? The buttons are right next to each other but I don't think this has anything to do with it. Additionally, I also commented out the entire body of the lap function and the same thing happened.

```
 @IBAction func Reset(_ sender: Any)
{
    min = 0
    sec = 0
    mil = 0
    timer.invalidate()
    createLabel()
    var i = 0
    while i < list.count
    {
        list[i].removeFromSuperview()
        i = i + 1
    }
    running = false

}



@IBAction func Lap(_ sender: UIButton)
{

    let word = UILabel()
    list.append(word)

    word.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 50)
    word.text = make()
    word.sizeToFit()

    word.frame.origin = CGPoint(x:187.5,y:700)
    self.Scroll.addSubview(word)
    word.center = CGPoint(x:187,y:last)
    last = last + 50


    Scroll.contentSize.height = Scroll.contentSize.height + 50

}
```

Comment: Additionally, I also commented out the entire body of the lap function and the same thing happened

Comment: It sounds like you wired up 2 @IBActions to your lap button.  Control-click on your Lap button and delete the connection to Reset().

Comment: wow that was easy thank you so much!

Comment: Function and variable names (`lap`, `reset`, `scrollView`) should begin with a lowercase letter. The code in your question is not causing this to happen. Please can you show any code that updates/does anything with the buttons you mentioned. If you could add a screenshot of the nib that would be helpful too. :-)

Comment: I'm guessing you copied the Reset Button to make your Lap button.  If the @IBAction is connected when you copy a button, you get that connection as well with the new button.

Comment: @vacawama good catch. You should add that as an answer :-)

Comment: @Fogmeister, I added an answer after searching fruitlessly to find a duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you wired up two `@IBAction`s to your *Lap* button. <kbd>Control</kbd>-click on your Lap button in the *Storyboard* and delete the connection to `Reset()` by clicking on the `x` next to the action.

[image: unhook IBAction in Storyboard]

I'm guessing you copied the *Reset* button to make your *Lap* button. If the `@IBAction` is connected when you copy a button, you get that connection as well with the new button.  So if you add a connection to the new button, it doesn't replace the previous action but instead becomes a second action.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might have hooked up both buttons with same IBAction function. Make a print statement inside both IBAction functions and see what happens. Or, delete both IBAction functions (and referencing outlets from the storyboard) and re-connect. Also, check in the connection inspector (top right in storyboard) to see if you have any dead outlets.

Answer (score 0):

Start debugging and you'll find the solution. Start from the first point. Like adding buttons in the storyboard and then connecting them to View Controller. I think you have connected one button to multiple actions.